# Circular domain for Plot3D

Tags: plotting

*Mathematica*'s `Plot3D` works with **rectangular** domains.

In other words, we write:

```
Plot3D[Function, {x,a,b}, {y,c,d}]
```

Here the domain is $[a,b]\times[c,d]$. And hence, the surface is cut in a rectangular projection.

But, what if I want my surface to be cut otherwise, say, as a circle?

To illustrate my question, I present two different images of a paraboloid:

[image: Paraboloids.]

The first one is drawn with `Plot3D` and the second one is obtained by revolution of a simple parabola.

`RevolutionPlot3D`, however, generates surfaces, which have axial symmetry only.

What should I do, if I have a non-symmetrical surface and want to cut its edges in a circle (or, if it's possible, in any other way)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`RegionFunction` is what you are looking for.

```
Plot3D[4 Sin[x] + y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 100]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Since version 10 you can also specify the plotting domain using a geometric region. In your case, for instance, you could use:

```
Plot3D[3 x^2 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This allows for interesting constructions using the full power of geometric regions:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2,
 {x, y} ∈ RegionDifference[
    Polygon[CirclePoints[6]],
    Polygon[0.5 CirclePoints[3]]
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 13):

> `RevolutionPlot3D`, however, generates surfaces, which have axial symmetry only.

Actually, `RevolutionPlot3D[]` can be used to plot in cylindrical coordinates, and not just surfaces of revolution. Not many people seem to be aware of this.

To use paw's example:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[With[{x = r Cos[θ], y = r Sin[θ]}, 4 Sin[x] + y],
                 {r, 0, 10}, {θ, -π, π}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 & , #2 &}]
```

[image: surface cut to a circle]

Comment: What has `RevolutionPlot3D` ever done to you to deserve such abuse?

Comment: @Brett, hey, `CylindricalPlot3D[]` up and left me cold. What else was I to do, but find another?

Comment: I'm only talking about the conversion back to cartesian coordinates. General plotting in cylindrical coordinates is most definitely a `RevolutionPlot3D` feature. :-)

Comment: Oh, you mean the mesh? Well, I suppose I could've stuck with the default mesh...

Comment: No, I mean using cylindrical coordinates to plot $f(x,y)$ instead of $f(r,t)$.

Comment: Ah, that can't be helped; it's my usual technique for cutting Cartesian functions into other shapes. :)